# Authorization issue in openshift online3

Tags: eclipse, github, openshift

Whenever I try to deploy java application from GitHub to openshift I get authorization issue. This is the log file I am getting while trying to push the image from git to openshift :

```
Cloning "https://github.com/niladri3/niladritest2.git" ...
Commit: aa3e9851141def47bb9e93d15e5e1ff80224f63e ((commited))
Author: niladri3 <1993niladri@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Jun 28 12:30:22 2017 +0530
Pulling image "registry.access.redhat.com/jboss-webserver-3/webserver30-tomcat8-openshift@sha256:37672e770d6ad5697fffc6fec6eae09108664bb34e8b01768ee58f381d80454a" ...
Pulling image "registry.access.redhat.com/jboss-webserver-3/webserver30-tomcat8-openshift@sha256:37672e770d6ad5697fffc6fec6eae09108664bb34e8b01768ee58f381d80454a" ...
Found pom.xml... attempting to build with 'mvn -e -Popenshift -DskipTests -Dcom.redhat.xpaas.repo.redhatga package -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true '
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Duser.home=/home/jboss -Duser.name=jboss
Using Apache Maven 3.0.5 (Red Hat 3.0.5-17)
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_131, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-2.b11.el7_3.x86_64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: ANSI_X3.4-1968
OS name: "linux", version: "3.10.0-514.25.2.el7.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Duser.home=/home/jboss -Duser.name=jboss
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Dashboard Maven Webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

Downloaded: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-filtering/1.0-beta-2/maven-filtering-1.0-beta-2.jar (33 KB at 437.9 KB/sec

Downloaded: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.3.1/xstream-1.3.1.jar (422 KB at 1839.7 KB/sec)
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [Dashboard] in [/home/jboss/source/target/ROOT]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [/home/jboss/source/src/main/webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [196 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: /home/jboss/source/target/ROOT.war
[INFO] WEB-INF/web.xml already added, skipping
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 36.622s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jun 29 06:13:56 UTC 2017
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/307M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The requested profile "openshift" could not be activated because it does not exist.
Copying all target war artifacts from /home/jboss/source/target directory into /opt/webserver/webapps for later deployment...
'/home/jboss/source/target/ROOT.war' -> '/opt/webserver/webapps/ROOT.war'

Pushing image 172.30.254.23:5000/jd-dashboardcheck/tomcat:latest ...
error: build error: Failed to push image: unauthorized: authentication required
```

At the end it's saying authentication required even when earlier I used to push in the same way and the image always used to load.

```
Things I have used:
Eclipse: Maven--In the POM.xml i have changed the filename directory to ROOT
Pushed the project in the GitHub.
Getting error at the time of pushing it from github to Openshift online 3.
```

Please help if you know the reason why I am getting this error. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are some current issues with builds failing on starter-us-east-1 when pushing images. This is noted at:

- https://status.starter.openshift.com/

with details in:

- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1462542

See if that matches your problem.